# How to test Paypal/Payflow Silent Post?

Tags: paypal

The only method I see to creating a testing environment for Payflow's silent post is to set the Recurring Billing to be billed daily. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simulator of your own to use for testing.  Just make an HTML form with the action set to your listener URL and hidden fields matching the parameters/values you might expect to get from a silent post.  This way you can test directly in a browser and see results on screen, which can help with troubleshooting/debugging, too.